# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2={2n^3+3n^2+n\over 6}$ using the identity ${r\choose r}+{r+1\choose r}+{r+2\choose r}+...+{n\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2={2n^3+3n^2+n\over 6}$ using the identity ${r\choose r}+{r+1\choose r}+{r+2\choose r}+...+{n\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1}$. I fail to see the connection. Before that I had to prove the identity in a combinatoric fashion, but I see no valid connection or implementation that has something to do with a sum of squares and I am afraid there is a solid step I am missing here. Could someone put some light on it? I saw no prior references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $r=2$
then we have
$$\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}=\dfrac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}$$
since $\binom{k}{2}=\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}$,then 
$$\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{k}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2-\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Was really strange of me to not arrive at the second equality. Thank you.